# By default, how are Node.js sessions handled?

Tags: javascript, session, node.js

So, I did a basic setup:

```
app.use(express.session({secret:'abc'}));
```

I did not install redis or any database.  By default, how does Node.js handle sessions?  Where do they store it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default the session middleware uses the memory store bundled with Connect, however many implementations exist.

http://expressjs.com/guide.html#session-support

The memory store in Connect: http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session-memory.html

So, it's just an in-memory data store (I'm guessing something like a mapping from session ID to `{}`).

Comment: But I didn't initialize any "memorystore". It got initialized automaticaly?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's just the default implementation.

Comment: if server goes down will sessions be there stil or for that i have to use redis/mongo ??

Answer (score 0):

here's how you do sessions

```
// how you setup session
var MemoryStore = require('express').session.MemoryStore;
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat", store: new MemoryStore({ reapInterval:  60000 * 10 })}));

//to store sessions
app.post('/',function(req,res){
  req.session.user = "myname"; 
});
```